# SQLite3: Find a user based on their ID using a function

Tags: sqlite

I want to make a function:

```
def UserGameDetails(UserID):

SQL = '''SELECT U.FirstName, U.LastName, COUNT(*) AS TotalGames
         FROM User U INNER JOIN Game G
         ON U.Id = G.UserId
         WHERE U.Id = ? '''
```

As you can see, the function can be called by writing for example: UserGameDetails(3),
and you will recieve all relevant information for the user with ID 3.

How can I make it so that my function knows that what the user puts in the brackets, is the UserID it is looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `execute()` and bind the parameter.  Note that your query should have a `GROUP BY` clause.

```py
SQL = '''SELECT U.FirstName, U.LastName, COUNT(*) AS TotalGames
         FROM User U INNER JOIN Game G
             ON U.Id = G.UserId
         WHERE U.Id = ?
         GROUP BY U.FirstName, U.LastName'''
id = 3
results = cursor.execute(SQL, (id,))

for row in results:
    first = row["FirstName"]
    last = row["LastName"]
    count = row["TotalGames"]
    print("User '" + first + " " + last + "' has played " + str(count) + " games.")
```

Comment: And if I want the the results to be delivered in a formated string like: "User 'Jake' 'Nicholson' has played '5' games."?

Comment: Access the columns as e.g. `results[0]['FirstName']`

Comment: When I try returning that, it says the sqlite3.Cursor is not subscriptable.

Comment: I ended up using row[0] instead of row["FirstName"] etc.. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Yes...change your query to _select_ the output you want, e.g. use: `SELECT 'User ' + U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName + ' has played ' + COUNT(*) + ' games.'`